# React leaflet map print

Tags: leaflet, printing, leaflet-plugins, mapfish-print, mapfish-print-2

I want to print a leaflet map in PDF/Image formats and It will be contained,

- WMS layers
- Polygon, Markers, Polylines etc

I'm using a leaflet map with React Typescript. Related versions are,

- react-leaflet - 2.7.0
- react - 16.13.1
- leaflet - 1.6.0

I tried https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport leaflet-easyprint and  leaflet.browser.print but didn't get a promising result.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-easyprint

> ```
> import { Map, withLeaflet} from "react-leaflet";
>
> import PrintControlDefault from 'react-leaflet-easyprint';
>
> const PrintControl = withLeaflet(PrintControlDefault as any);
>
>  <Map>
>     <PrintControl ref={printMapRef} 
>      position="topleft" 
>      sizeModes={['Current', 'A4Portrait', 'A4Landscape']} 
>      hideControlContainer={false} />
>  </Map>
> ```

Typescript Error:

> Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject; position: string; sizeModes: string[]; hideControlContainer: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<ContextProps, "leaflet"> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<ContextProps, "leaflet"> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

2. https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.browser.print

> ```
> importLfrom"leaflet";
> import {​​​​​ useLeaflet }​​​​​ from"react-leaflet";
> const {​​​​​ map }​​​​​ = useLeaflet();
>
> (L as any).control.browserPrint({​​​​​
> position:'topright'
> }​​​​​).addTo(map);
> ```

This works fine, but cannot print WMS layers.

Does anyone have an idea about any plugin or library which is match with above-mentioned conditions?

Comment: I've had good success with [leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter)

Comment: Thanks, @SethLutske, leaflet-simple-map-screenshoter is working